# CMake TARGET_RUNTIME_DLLS is empty

Tags: cmake, wxwidgets

I have git cloned, built (with MSVC for both Debug and Release) and then installed wxWidgets:

```
cmake -B build wxWidgets
cmake --build build --config <CONFIG>
cmake --install build --prefix my_install --config <CONFIG>
```

with `<CONFIG> = Debug` and `<CONFIG> = Release`.

Then I used the following CMake script to link against it, as [suggested by the wiki](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/CMake):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(Test)

add_executable(Test WIN32 Main.cpp)

# wxWidgets
SET(wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../thirdparty/my_install)
find_package(wxWidgets COMPONENTS core base REQUIRED)
include(${wxWidgets_USE_FILE})
target_link_libraries(Test PRIVATE ${wxWidgets_LIBRARIES})

# Copy runtime DLLs to the directory of the executable.
add_custom_command(TARGET Test POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "Runtime Dlls: $<TARGET_RUNTIME_DLLS:Test>"
        )
```

My goal is to automatically copy the DLLs into the directory of the built executable, so that they can be found at runtime. For that I'm using the `TARGET_RUNTIME_DLLS` generator expression (follwing the [sample code in the docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-stage/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#genex:TARGET_RUNTIME_DLLS)). In the code above, I only print out the expression at build time for testing purposes. The problem is that it is empty.

The approach worked for me before when installing and linking SDL, but SDL provides package configuration files which create imported targets, defining the DLL location(s) via `IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE` or `IMPORTED_LOCATION_DEBUG`. For wxWidgets one is apparently supposed to use the FindwxWidgets.cmake script shipped with CMake, which sadly doesn't define the produced binaries. Maybe that's why `TARGET_RUNTIME_DLLS` isn't populated.

**Does anyone know, either how to get `TARGET_RUNTIME_DLLS` filled or how to obtain the list of built wxWidgets DLLs for the current configuration (Release/Debug) post build copying?**

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I am dealing with a similar problem.

First sanity checks:

1. You have to work on windows platform otherwise this feature does not
   work.
2. Your Cmake is 3.21 or above

Next comes fuzzy part. I think the library that you are trying to include have to be a `Shared Imported` library and you have to set a `set_target_properties` for `IMPORTED_IMPLIB` which is a path to a .lib file of sort (dll import library, I think it is called) So you have to make sure that it is all set in the package library that you trying to link with your executable.

If you have those dll avaiable and you just want to use them and not actually build them then you can write your own cmake script that will do just what I said above. Then you can include that cmake file in your project and then link against your app.

Note: I also work on similar issue right now and what I just said have not been working very reliably. I got some dlls to be copied and some do not.

Edit:

Cmake docs give a more detailed explanation on how this library setting should look like if you use find_package feature.

Found here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#imported-libraries

> An UNKNOWN library type is typically only used in the implementation
> of Find Modules. It allows the path to an imported library (often
> found using the find_library() command) to be used without having to
> know what type of library it is. This is especially useful on Windows
> where a static library and a DLL's import library both have the same
> file extension.